# Using static class variables without allocationg them

Tags: c++, c++11, static-variables

#### Background

So earlier today I was implementing a thin wrapper to `std::ofstream` that allowed me to write to .csv files easily. I wanted to override the `<<` operator to write value followed by a comma, and then when the time came for a new line, I would print a backspace character and then a new line. I decided to implement the new line behaviour as a template specialization as follows:

```
// *this << value; => prints the value to the csv file
// *this << CsvWriter::BREAK; => goes to the next line of the csv file
// Example:
//   CsvWriter csv("test.csv", {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"});
//   csv << "Value 1" << 2 << 3.25 << CsvWriter::BREAK;
class CsvWriter {
 public:
  CsvWriter(const char *fname, std::vector<const char *> headers);
  CsvWriter() = delete;
  CsvWriter(const CsvWriter &) = delete;
  CsvWriter &operator=(const CsvWriter &) = delete;
  ~CsvWriter() = default;

  // Used for the template specialization below
  static struct LineBreak {} BREAK;

  template <typename T>
  CsvWriter &operator<<(T t);

 private:
  std::ofstream out_;
  bool first_ = true;  // true when printing first element of line
};

template <typename T>
CsvWriter &CsvWriter::operator<<(T t) {
  if (!first_) {
    out_ << ',';
  } else {
    first_ = false;
  }
  out_ << t;
  return *this;
}

// This is the specialization for newlines.
// If anything of type LineBreak is passed to this function, this executes.
template <>
CsvWriter &CsvWriter::operator<<(LineBreak) {
  out_ << std::endl;
  first_ = true;  // Reset first for next line
  return *this;
}

// The constructor gives an example use of the template specialization
CsvWriter::CsvWriter(const char *fname, std::vector<const char *> headers)
    : out_(fname) {
  for (const char *header : headers) {
    *this << header;  // Prints each string in header
  }
  *this << BREAK;  // Goes to the next line of the csv
}
```

#### Brief Explanation

This code works perfectly as is, and compiles with no complaints in gcc. However, I noticed that I was technically not allocating memory to the value `BREAK`. So to check it out, I tried printing the value of `&CsvWriter::BREAK` and ran into a linking error (which makes sense, I'm asking for the address of something that's not in memory). And furthermore, if I add the line `CsvWriter::LineBreak CsvWriter::BREAK;` after the class definition, then I can print the value of `&CsvWriter::BREAK` no problem (which also makes sense because now I've given it memory.

From this, I can puzzle together that if the value is never used in any compilation unit, the linker will never look for the value and never complain about it. But if I use it (such as grabbing the address), the linker will try and link the name, and not find anything.

#### Question

While I find this result very useful for what I'm trying to do, I'm curious, is this technically against the C++11 standard? Or is this perfectly valid code? If not, is there a better way to do this with a similarly clear and simple interface?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @SamVarshavchik. I'm editing the question right now to just remove that so it's not distracting!

Comment: "if the value is never used in any compilation unit, the linker will never look for the value and never complain about it" - true, but that's how it has always been in C++. You are not required to define what you don't use (even if you declared it previously). So, the question here is what constitutes a "use" of `CsvWriter::BREAK`. The modern language requires a definition if and only if the object is *odr-used*. Takling a pointer definitely makes it odr-used. As for passing it by value... interesting question.

Comment: Printing a backspace character followed by a newline doesn't remove the comma from the file. So it seems like your whole approach is wrong.

Comment: @Barmar I agree that backspace was not a valid solution, but minimal additional logic (edited in above) fixes that.

Comment: @AnT Thanks! My thought process right now is going along the lines of the compiler optimizing the passing of the value into the function away since the value is not odr-used inside the function. I would think this is a required optimization when I specify the argument as `LineBreak`. But if I had specified the argument as `LineBreak lb`, it still compiles and runs. At this point, you could argue that the value should be passed? Or am I missing the point, and passing by value itself doesn't count as odr-used?

Comment: @define cindy const: Knowing how compiler works, I'd say that passing an *empty* object by value does not have to make it odr-used. But in general case (for non-empty objects) the language specification would require a definition in this case. I don't think it makes an exception for empty objects (I could be wrong though).

Comment: @AnT that's pretty interesting! I think I'm going to add the line `CsvWriter::LineBreak CsvWriter::BREAK;` just to be sure. If gcc is not linking to it, it should get discarded from the final binary anyhow, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is technically an ill-formed program.

What is likely happening is that the compiler is smart enough to see that the value of the parameter to the overloaded function is never used. Consequently, the compiler does not emit the code to pass the unused `BREAK` value to the overloaded `<<` operator. Since no reference to the symbol gets generated, the linker does not complain.

But if you explicitly generate a reference to the object, the link will fail, of course.

The C++ standard does not require the compiler to perform this optimization, as such this is ill-formed. So, technically this is, indeed, not allowed by the C++ standard.

Comment: I see your point, but what I'm wondering, is does the act of passing an object to a function by value always constitute as a use of that value (i.e. requiring somewhere to link against)? If when you don't reference a value, it doesn't need to exist, then if a function doesn't use the value, should passing the value to the function require it to exist? I think that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: It's not whether or not passing an object to a function by value constitutes a use, it does. It's that a C++ compiler is permitted to optimize the compiled code in any fashion, as long as the end result is the same. The only requirement is that the program is well-formed. Here, the compiler figures out that overloaded operator does not use its parameter, so it doesn't need to pass it. Not passing the parameter produces the same results as passing the parameter, presuming that the program is well-formed. Now, if `BREAK` was defined as a `volatile` object, this would be a different story...

Comment: gotcha. In that case, I'll add the line `CsvWriter::LineBreak CsvWriter::BREAK;` to make sure the program is considered valid.